# save page as html along with contents

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a simple JS function that lets the user input their first and last name and `onclick` displays their full name.

Is there a way to include the user's submitted content in the text field when the user saves the page as html and reopens it?

```
function getFullName() {

    var firstName, lastName, fullName;

    firstName = document.Application.txtFirstName.value; 
    lastName  = document.Application.txtLastName.value;
    fullName  = firstName + " " + lastName;
    document.Application.txtFullName.value = fullName;
}
```

Comment: I doubt it will be possible, unless you are editing the saved HTML manually.

Comment: @janaspage:  The user inputs his name(first and last) and onclick he gets his full name and then he tries to save it using the save page as option in the browser..he should be able to view his name in text fields when he reopens the saved page....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest workaround would be that if a user enters text into an `input` element and then—before submitting—prints the page to PDF (`Menubar > File > Print > Save as PDF` or the like), their content is included in the resultant PDF file. Would that help?

Otherwise, you could write a function to be executed upon `click` of your `button`, and have that function first [`preventDefault`](http://devdocs.io/dom/event.preventdefault) (preventing it from reloading the page and clearing the form fields, if its `type="submit"`), and then have it write their name to a variable and prompt them to save the page:

http://jsbin.com/yelun/1/edit

```
<form id="nameForm">
  First Name<br />
  <input type="text" name="first" /><br />
  <br />
  Last Name<br />
  <input type="text" name="last" /><br />
  <br />
  <button type="submit" onclick="processForm(event)">Submit</button>
</form>

var processForm = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = document.getElementById('nameForm');
  var firstName = form.first.value;
  var lastName = form.last.value;
  var fullName  = firstName + ' ' + lastName;
  alert('Hello, ' + fullName + '. Please now save this page as HTML via your browser\'s `File` menu.');
};
```

Additionally, you could try **wrapping your button in an `a` or `area` element, setting that element's `href` to your web page's URL, and adding a [`download` attribute](http://developers.whatwg.org/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download) to that element**. This is not something I can easily demo in a generic online sandbox, but the `download` attribute:

> …indicates that the author intends the hyperlink to be used for downloading a resource.

Essentially, it makes the browser download the linked location, rather than navigating the browser to the linked location.

If you can't wrap the `button` or its text in an `a` or `area` to your liking, you could create, style, and script a `div` to look like a `button`, and wrap that `div` in an `a` or `area`.

Comment: :Works fine with firefox...but will figure something out for chrome... much obliged though

Comment: upvoted,and thanks for ur vote too atleast now  I am a eligible voter (: